# retrieve lost code after merge went wrong

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, merge-conflict-resolution

So we made a rookie mistake, One of our project team members had forgotten to commit for a couple of weeks, (some of which were vacation) but then when he did commit he did something wrong, most of the code he wrote has been overwritten with what was on the server after trying to resolve all the conflicts automatically.

So is there any way to get the code he used to have on his PC back? because a lot of work has been lost and we can't really afford to make it all again.

So just to clarify, the code which is lost is not on the server, it were his uncommitted changes on his client machine.

We are using the team foundation server and visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Code lost that never made it into source is lost. This is one of the biggest selling points of distributed version control like Git.

Comment: How does Git solve this? Assuming the files were never committed would it matter if it was tfs or git?

Comment: Git solves this by allowing you to commit to local repo before pushing to the server, allowing you to rollback/forward locally. Usually not checking into the server is based on fear of breaking the build, but checking in locally you can be less fearful, and check in more often.

Comment: Agreed, my point was it's still being committed / checked in (albeit locally)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at folder:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\
```

In my case, searching by method name, i can recover a mistake merge =)

Comment: Exact class names were not present ( eg: MyClass.cs ) but had other system generated values ( eg: vctmp8020_737984.cs ) so, looking through the last 5 or 6 for todays date I found my lost changes!

Comment: Yes... in my case, my search for files containing text CLASSNAME... =)

Comment: YES! I found the merge files in this folder. It saved my day, Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your using Windows 7 or similar check for previous version of the file on his/her computer, right click the file options should be their

Answer (score 0):

If you have not compiled after doing the merge, you can use DotPeek by JetBrains to decompile the assembly and get your code back